# How to mimic the anchor function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashtag

I need some javascript that will **extract an anchor ('hashtag' in the case below) from the page's url and autoscroll to the tag with that name**.

Here's an example url: www.somelink.com/post1/#hashtag

I tried putting the url in an anchor tag like this; 
`<a name="hashtag" href="www.somelink.com/post1/#hashtag">` 
and it works fine. But I want to mimic that functionality in code.

I tried doing it in jQuery, but there I need to have an `id` defined.

I searched the forum but i couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: @DannyBeckett I think the OP IS doing that, but since it's his first post; and there's probably a language barrier too; he doesn't know to what extent he should include the detail of his problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking to extract the hashtag from the url first, 
then go to that part in the page?

like this?;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var tag = window.url.split('#');
   tag = tag[tag.length - 1];

   $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("[name='" + tag + "']").offset().top
   },10);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
$(window).scrollTop($("#someId").offset().top - 20);
```

Comment: "I tried with jQvery to but there I need to have `id`"

Answer (score 0):

Playing off Omer's answer, except using a name instead of the ID:

```
$(window).scrollTop($("[name="+hashtag+"]").offset().top - 20);
```